# Render different react-components depending on property-value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build an input-component in `ReactJs` using typescript.
An input can have different types, e.g. `text`, `date`, `select` or `textarea`.

Depending on the given type the rendered control can be different. If set to `text`, `<input type="text" />` should be returned.
On the other hand, if the type is `select`, `<select></select>` should be returned.

These are my props:

```
export interface IInputProps {
    type?: "text" | "checkbox" | "date" | "select"| "textarea";
}
```

In my `render`-function I now try to figure out, what should be returned:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    const { type } = this.props;

    let Element: JSX.Element = null;

    switch (type) {
        case "text":
            Element = <input type={type} />;
            break;
        case "select":
            const { children } = this.props.selectProps;
            Element = <select>{children}</select>;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`The type ${type} is currently not implemented. If needed, do so.`);
    }

    const classes = classNames("form-control");

    // return the markup of the final element
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            { /* below the error is thrown */ }
            <Element ref={/* some internal handling here */} className={classes} /> 
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

However, this code throws

> Error TS2604  (TS) JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Note that the example is a simplified version of the problem. There will be more type-specific properties, e.g. attributes `rows` and `cols` for `textarea`.

What would be the correct way to achieve this? What type must `Element` be? Also note, that I have to set attributes, which may not be available, e.g. `type` is not available on `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're doubling up on `React.createElement` calls. Remember that:

```
let element = <div />
```

turns into this:

```
let element = React.createElement('div')
```

so your code:

```
Element = <input type={type} />;
```

and:

```
<Element ref={/* some internal handling here */} className={classes} />
```

is like doing:

```
let Element = React.createElement(React.createElement('input'))
```

which doesn't make sense.

**Solution:**

1) evaluate your already created element:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {Element} 
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

This means any props you want to add, like `ref`, you'll need to add when creating the element:

```
Element = <input type={type} ref={...} />;
```

This may seem arduous, luckily you can just make a component on the fly:

```
// notice the function, not directly calling createElement
Element = props => <input type={type} {...props} />;
```

Then this code will work:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Element ref={/* some internal handling here */} className={classes} /> 
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

**update:** I almost never use `ref` so I forgot about the stateless warning. quick fix:

```
// notice the component, not directly calling createElement
Element = class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input type={type} {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems good so far. But now, I have two other issues. First it throws `Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.` On the other hand, how can I pass directly `this.props.selectProps` to the Element?

Comment: what are you using `ref` for anyways?

Comment: I check the underlying element's `validity`-property for errors which I would display below the input if any. Therefore I need access to the DOM-element.

Comment: well you don't *need* access to the dom element. just do your validations on event handlers like `onChange` etc

Comment: in fact, you definitely *shouldn't* be using `ref` for that purpose

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit in detail on why exactly using html5's constraint-validation is a bad idea?

Comment: oh i'm not saying that at all, i'm saying you don't need `ref` to use it. handle the validation attribute in event handlers

Comment: So you mean I should access in the handler via `ev.target.validity`? Currently I use the ref-callback and `componentDidMount` to set the state-property of type `ValidityState`.

Comment: so a) yes I think that's cleaner, b) a very simple fix to using refs is just make a quick class instead a of a function. will update answer